# How to access component data from flatpickr event method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flatpickr

I'm currently using the [vue-flatpickr-component](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component) to create much nicer date input fields. Now I have an "onClose()" method (see code below) to check if the entered date is valid.

*I removed much of the code to make it more readable.*

If it's not valid it should change a boolean value to true, but I can't access the value in the data from the onClose method. Does anyone know how I can do that? Thanks

```
export default {
  components: {
    flatPickr
  },
  data () {
    return {
      invalidDate: false,
      datepickerConfig: {
        wrap: true,
        altInput: true,
        allowInput: true,
        onClose () {
          // Set invalidDate to true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access your data object from inside the `onClose()` function, you have to convert it to a arrow function, because the context of `this` changed. [Understanding binding and 'this'](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/2a4ac91f9f42ec0ef9cd0d18e4e71262)

```
...
onClose: () => {
   this.invalidDate = true;
}
...
```